# What's the syntax of "It's everything you've ever heard it is"?

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clauses, syntax, emphasis, conversational-deletion

Source: "Boardwalk Empire" Season 01 Episode 07 00:29:19

> **Mary Dittrich** (the girlfriend of the photographer Robert Dittrich): Relax. It's not like he saw us together.
>
> **Angela Darmody** (the wife of Jimmy Darmody): Nucky Thompson didn't get where he is by being native. That look on his face -- He knows something's amiss.
>
> **Mary**: So he knows. And then what?
>
> **Angela**: Well, he could stop giving me money... You're so good. I depond on this man.
>
> **Mary**: What about Jimmy?
>
> **Angela**: I would have thought he'd send something. If not for me, for Tommy.
>
> **Mary**: You just may have to get a job, my sweet.
>
> **Angela**: I know... Anything from that art dealer in New York?
>
> **Mary**: No. But Robert's friend Jonathan is coming in town to look at some real estate. He works at Washington Square Gallery in Greenwich Village. He's agreed to assess your work.
>
> **Angela**: Greenwich Village? Can you imagine?
>
> **Mary**: *It's everything you've ever heard it is*.

[image]

I know all the words, but I have difficulties in grammatical analysis.

I think "*you've ever heard*" is an attributive clause that modifies "*everything*", so the sentence can be reduced as "*It's everything it is*". And what is "*It's everything it is*"?

---

related questions: [What's the meaning of "occidental" in "Boardwalk Empire"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335839/whats-the-meaning-of-occidental-in-boardwalk-empire)

Comment: People have heard all sorts of (presumably good) things about 'it'. The speaker says that all these things (_everything you've ever heard_) are true.

Comment: Does it help to think of it as "It is everything **that** you have ever heard **that** it is"?

Comment: I can understand the first "that", but what's the second "that"? Also an introductory conjunction of an attributive clause (*that it is*)? @stangdon

Comment: This looks like a dialogue between two people. Can you write the names of the two speaking? For example, Anna: *He's agreed to assess your work*. // Lucy: *Greenwich Village?*  P.S What "work" is being referred to? Paintings?

Comment: It's beyond the scope of this site to completely break down a sentence grammatically, so please [edit your question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/335710/edit) to tell us what specifically you don't understand or where you get confused. For instance, maybe you're confused because there's two subjects and two conjugated verbs without a conjunction.

Comment: I transcripted their conversation. @Mari-LouA

Comment: I edited the question. How to understand "*It's everything it is*"? @gotube

Comment: See my original comment. "It"  (Greenwich Village? the gallery?) is just as good as Angela has heard people say that it is. Not _It's everything it is_, but _It **is** [everything you have heard that] it  is._