# What's the meaning of "occidental" in "Boardwalk Empire"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

source: "Boardwalk Empire" Season 01 Episode 08 00:28:59

> for my money it's the occidental in D.C.

[image]

According to dictionaries, "occidental" means "Of or relating to the countries of the Occident or their peoples or cultures; western."

What sences in this context?

---

related questions: [What's the syntax of "It's everything you've ever heard it is"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335710/whats-the-syntax-of-its-everything-youve-ever-heard-it-is)

Comment: I see you added some explanation of the context to your other question. Can you do the same for this one?

Comment: 1 You can see the context in Michael Harvey's answer. 2 I added more explanation to the other question, which I invite you to review. @KateBunting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The subtitle is badly transcribed; the word 'Occidental' should start with a capital O because it is a proper noun (the name of a famous restaurant in real life, that still exists).**

The previous dialogue shows that the speaker is talking about the meat served in the restaurant in which they are eating, and its quality.

> **I'll tell you, as much as they crow about their meat here,**
>
> for my money it's the Occidental in DC.
>
> Your money? When's the last time you paid for a dinner?
>
> Right after McKinley was elected.

They are eating meat; the speaker says 'they' (people who have eaten where they are) 'crow about (praise loudly) the meat here'. However, he uses an idiom 'for my money' ('in my opinion') to say that 'it's the Occidental in D.C. ' (his opinion is that the Occidental Restaurant in Washington D.C. is either better, or the best, for meat).

Then the other guy uses the literal, non-idiomatic meaning of 'for my money' to jokingly suggest the first speaker is mean with money. He asks when he last paid for a dinner, and the reply is 'Right (immediately) after [President] McKinley was elected [in 1897]'. This is also a joke; the series is set in the 1920s.

Comment: 1 Very helpful. I get the point, and learn a new phrase "for my money". By the way, I can see the Chinese translation was wrong. 2 Why is "*Right after McKinley was elected.*" also a joke?

Comment: It's an obvious exaggeration to say that he last paid for a dinner some 25 years before!